Unsuccesfully adding font in pyside6
I try to add font Gotham Narrow into my pyqt apps. Below is my simple script.
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
fontpath = "GothamNarrow-Bold.otf"
_id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(fontpath)
font = QFontDatabase.font("Gotham Narrow", "Gotham Narrow Bold", 120)

print(QFontDatabase.families())
print(f"id:{_id}")
print (f"is_exist {QFile.exists(font_path)}")

pyqt  : PySide6 v6.8.0.2
os    : Sonoma 14.6.1
python: 3.12.4
_id always returns -1, it seems that the font is not imported.
I put GothamNarrow-Bold.otf file in the same level with my script.
QFile.exists(font_path) returns True.
Any suggestion?

Are you actually running the script from its path? What is the output of QFile.exists('GothamNarrow-Bold.otf')? If it returns False, then either the file is not actually there (maybe it's the wrong name, or it's a link), or the working directory is not the same of the running script. Note that your call to font() is probably invalid, as that "Narrow" is part of the font family, not the style. Use applicationFontFamilies() to get the correct family identifier(s). Also, add relevant env info (OS and Qt version).

QFile.exists('GothamNarrow-Bold.otf')  returns True . OS: Sonoma 14.6.1 and pyside6 (I assue it has pyqt6)..

Works fine for me on Linux using Qt 6.8.0 with both PySide-6.8.0.2 and PyQt6-6.8.0 (i.e. print(QFontInfo(font).family()) outputs Gotham Narrow).
